# Fragment with TextInputLayout crashes app on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-6.0-marshmallow

I've discovered the following issue. I use Material Design' class `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` in XML layout.

When I inflate this layout in fragment, my app falls with the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #563: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

The fall occures on **Samsung Galaxy S7** with **Android 6.0.1**. When I start the app on **Lenovo A319** with **Android 4.4.2** everything goes fine, no crash.
When I use XML layout with `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` class for activity *(without any fragments)*, **Galaxy S7** works fine too.

It seems that there is something wrong on Marshmallow when app tries to inflate `android.support.design.widget` classes in fragment.

**Is there some way to fix that?**

Here is my code:

**DocumentEditFragment.java**

```
public class DocumentEditFragment extends BaseFragment {
...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_document_edit, container, false); // The app falls here on Galaxy S7
...
}
```

**DocumentActivity.java**

```
public class DocumentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DocumentEditFragment docEditFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_document);
        docEditFragment = new DocumentEditFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_document, docEditFragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**fragment_document_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"

    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/doc_edit_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
...
<!-- line #563 is below: -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/doc_edit_comment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="1st line\n2nd line"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:hint="Comment"
            android:textColorHint="#69202020"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_document.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_document"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="my.app.DocumentFragment"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
tools:context="my.app.DocumentFragment"
/>
```

**UPDATE:**

I've uploaded the sample project that produces the same error on **Galaxy S7 edge** as my working project does *(I cannot make public the corporate project)*. Here is the repository [**link**](https://github.com/YanaArtis/Fragment_with_TextInputLayout_Example).

**SOLVED**

I've moved the attribute
`android:theme="@style/TextLabel"`
from `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout />` into `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText />` - and everything goes fine! Thanks to Nico from Udacity for wise advice!